# Jmeter Integration with Ant- How to send the html report from ant from email

Tags: ant, jmeter

I have configured build.xml for Jmeter and html report is generated. I wanted to send this report as attachment in the email after the test execution. Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 0):

How do you trigger the execution? through Jenkins? If not, I would suggest you to use Jenkins for triggering the execution and takes care of email part.

The below article exactly explains what you are looking for!

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part2/

Comment: I tried using Jenkins, but the Report format using Jenkins is same as running the the Jmeter in Non GUI mode. Using Ant i have customized the report. Can i get the same customized report in Jenkins ?

Comment: Yes. Once you generated report, jenkins can take the report from the workspace and send it as an attachment or inline report

Answer (score 0):

You can add [Ant Mail Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/mail.html) in order to send the generated report over the email, the example required modification for sample [build.xml](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v4_0/extras/build.xml) file (you can find one under "extras" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<target name="send-email" depends="xslt-report">
    <mail user="johndoe@gmail.com"
          password="secret"
          ssl="yes"
          mailhost="smtp.gmail.com"
          mailport="465"
          subject="JMeter Test Results">
        <to address="recipient@example.com"/>
        <from address="johndoe@gmail.com"/>
        <attachments>
            <fileset dir="/path/to/test/results">
                <include name="**/*.html"/>
            </fileset>
        </attachments>
    </mail>
</target>
```

---

If you're not too familiar with Ant you can create second JMeter Test Plan with a single [SMTP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler) and configure it to send the .html result produced by the mail test plan to the specified recipients. See [Load Testing Your Email Server: How to Send and Receive E-mails with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter) article for more information on setting up JMeter for sending emails.